# How to use Kotlin coroutines for consuming messages with Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-amqp, kotlin-coroutines, spring-rabbit

I've [read](https://spring.io/blog/2019/04/12/going-reactive-with-spring-coroutines-and-kotlin-flow) that Spring Boot has support for Kotlin Coroutines since version 2.2.0. But when I try this with [spring amqp](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp) (version 2.2.0) like this:

```
@RabbitListener(...)
@Component
class EventConsumer {

    @RabbitHandler
    suspend fun consumeEvent(e: MyEvent) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then publish an event:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "my-routing-key", MyEvent("data"))
```

I get the following error:

```java
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public java.lang.Object com.x.y.EventConsumer(com.x.y.MyEvent,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit>)]
Bean [com.x.y.EventConsumer@1fce0403]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:143) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:132) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1569) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1488) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1476) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1467) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:1035) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
```

If I remove the `suspend` keyword then everything works as expected.

Do I need some special configuration for Spring AMQP to work with Kotlin Coroutines or is there no support for this yet?

Comment: First, maybe try to change `e: MyEvent` to `e: Object`.

Comment: If I remove the suspend keyword everything works as expected so I don't think that'll help?

Comment: Kotlin coroutines are not supported for rabbit listeners. Exactly what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Rabbit listener is an async by its nature already: that method is called from a thread pool in the listener container whenever a new message is pulled from the queue. What goal you would like to achieve with that `suspend` ?

Comment: I've probably misunderstood something so thanks for all comments. In my mind "suspend" is an alternative to the reactor data types such as "Mono". I.e. to answer "what I want to achieve" is to say that I want to be able to "achieve the same things I can achieve with a Mono". For example making concurrent requests to a web API or writing to a database in a non-blocking fashion (in this case using coroutines instead of the reactor types) as a side-effect after having received "MyEvent".

Comment: The problem is that a thread will be dedicated to this method until it completes. Coroutines are not just a way to be async. They're a way to be async without the overhead of a dedicated thread. We can use runBlocking here and then at least use coroutines within the method, but there's still one dedicated thread which should not be necessary. This has already been figured out for rest with webflux which integrates seamlessly with coroutines and won't unnecessarily block a thread. I would love to see the same with rabbit listeners.

Comment: @GaryRussell if Spring REST Controllers support `suspend fun` then it makes sense for `RabbitListener` to as well for consistency and convenience. The need is as simple as trying to use WebClient in your listener.

Comment: It will most likely need a completely new listener container implementation, written in Kotlin. Contributions are welcome. However, the existing SMLC will work fine with virtual threads from project loom, requiring virtually no effort at all.